# Codeigniter-restserver GET, POST funcionan pero PUT no

Tags: php, codeigniter, http

Hola estoy trabajando con Codeigniter 3.1.11 y la lib de restserver para hacer la api del sitio y con angularjs lo estoy consumiendo

https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Y al momento de hacer peticiones GET o POST si funciona bien, pero al momento de hacerlo con PUT este marca error, pero no logro reconocerlo para darle solucion

Entonces tengo mi estructura asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi controlador en codeigniter

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class NegociosController extends REST_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('NegociosModel');
    }

    public function negocio_put()
    {
        $data = $this->put();
        if ($data) {
            $negocio = $this->NegociosModel->put($data);
            $this->response($negocio, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        } else {
            $res = array(
                'error' => true,
                'mensaje' => 'No data'
            );
            $this->response($res, REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

}
```

Mi modelo en codeigniter NegociosModel:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

define('TABLA_NEGOCIOS', 'negocios');
class NegociosModel extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('ProductosModel');
    }

    public function put(array $datos)
    {
        $id = $datos['id'];
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update(TABLA_NEGOCIOS, $datos);
        $this->db->reset_query();
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $data = $this->db->select('*')->from(TABLA_NEGOCIOS)->get()->row();
        if (isset($data)) {
            $data->id = intval($data->id);
            $data->prioridad = intval($data->prioridad);
            $data->status = intval($data->status);
            $data->usuario = intval($data->usuario);
            $data->categoria = intval($data->categoria);
            $data->habilitado = intval($data->habilitado);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Mi controlador en angularjs negocioCtrl:

```
angular.module('app').controller('negocioCtrl', function (negocioService, sessionFactory, $timeout, $window) {
    const self = this;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;

    self.negocio = {
        "status": STATUS_ACTIVE,
        "imagen": null,
        "whatsapp": null,
        "habilitado": 0,
        "prioridad": 0,
        "etc..." : "etc..."
    };

    self.put = () => {
        // delete self.usuario.passwordv;
        self.negocio.usuario = self.USER.id;
        if (!self.whats) {
            self.negocio.whatsapp = null;
        }
        negocioService.put(self.negocio).then(data => {
            console.log('data: ', data);
            if (data) {
                sessionFactory.set('negocio', data)
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Exito',
                    text: '¡Actualizado correctamente!'
                });
                self.NEGOCIO = sessionFactory.get('negocio');
                self.isRegister = true;
            }
        }, error => {
            console.error('error: ', error);
        });
    }

});
```

Mi service en angularjs negocioService:

```
angular.module('app').service('negocioService', function ($q, factory) {

    const self = this;
    const baseURL = 'api/index.php/';
    const pathNegocios = baseURL + 'NegociosController';

    self.put = entity => {
        let path = pathNegocios + '/negocio';
        console.log('path: ', path);
        return $q((resolve, reject) => {
            factory.put(path, entity).then(success => {
                console.log('success: ', success);
                resolve(success);
            }, error => {
                console.log('error: ', error);
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    };

});
```

Mi factory :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').factory('factory', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        put: function (url, data) {
            return $http({
                url:  url,
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: data
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function (error) {
                return $q.reject(error);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Y el error que me arroja es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo este codigo si funciona en el localhost sin problema, pero en un servidor ya no funciona esa parte, ya trate con headers y el cors pero no da una solucion.

La idea tambien es poder hacer una PWA cuando todo el backend y frontend funcionen

Answer (score 0):

Solucion:

En el factory de mi app, tuve que cambiar el metodo PUT, para que sobreescribiera el metodo en el backend:

```
put: function (url, data) {
        return $http({
            url:  url,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PUT'
            },
            data: data
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function (error) {
            return $q.reject(error);
        });
    }
```